# Is there a way to create a sign function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, sign, elliptic-curve

```py
import re 
import math 
from random 
import randint 
import hashlib

P = (-0.15, 2.645)
Q = (0.7, 2.71)

max_mod = 1.158 * 10 ** 77

def SHA256_INT(text):
    return int(f'0x{hashlib.sha256(text.encode("ascii")).hexdigest()}', 0)

def ecc_double_slope(P):
    slope = (3 * P[0] ** 2) / (2 * P[1])
    return slope

def ecc_add(P, Q, slope):
    xr = slope ** 2 - P[0] - Q[0]
    yr = slope * (P[0] - xr) - P[1]
    return (xr, yr)

def ecc_double(P):
    slope = ecc_double_slope(P)
    sum0 = ecc_add(P, P, slope)
    return sum0

def ecc_double_for(P, limit):
    lis = []
    for i in range(limit):
        b = ecc_double(P)
        P = b
        lis.append((2 ** i, b))
    return lis

def greedy2(number):
    x = 0
    dub_lis = []
    add_lis = []

    while 2 ** x < number:
        dub_lis.append(2 ** x)
        x += 1
    x -= 1
    n = 2 ** x
    while n != number:
        y = x
        while n + (2 ** y) > number:
            y -= 1

        n += (2 ** y)
        x += 1
        add_lis.append(2 ** y)
    return len(dub_lis), add_lis

def ecc_main_add(P, Q):
    x1 = P[0]
    y1 = P[1]

    x2 = Q[0]
    y2 = Q[1]

    slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - y1)

    xr = slope ** 2 - x1 - x2
    yr = slope * (x1 - xr) - y1

    return xr, yr

def gen_points(gen, points):
    if gen == 1:
        return points
    elif gen > 1:
        if type(points) == int:
            point_curve = (points, math.sqrt(points ** 3 + 7))
        elif type(points) == tuple:
            point_curve = points
        point_steps = greedy2(gen)
        point_dub = point_steps[0]
        point_add = point_steps[1]
        dub_list = ecc_double_for(point_curve, point_dub)
        for i in point_add:
            b = ecc_main_add(dub_list[int(math.log(i, 2))][1], dub_list[-1][1])
        return b, gen
    elif gen == 0:
        return 0

def sign(messsage, private_key, public_key, G):
    global max_mod
    msg_hash = SHA256_INT(messsage)
    randnum = randint(2, max_mod)
    r = gen_points(randnum, G)[0]
    r_x = r[0]
    msg_hash = SHA256_INT(messsage)
    s = (r_x * private_key + msg_hash) / randnum
    p1 = gen_points(msg_hash/s, G)
    p2 = gen_points(r_x/s, public_key)
    p3 = ecc_main_add(p1, p2)

    return p3

pub, priv = gen_points(9756, P) 
print(sign('hello', priv, pub, P))
```

Hello, I'm trying to implement a way to sign messages using this tutorial:
https://learnmeabitcoin.com/beginners/digital_signatures_signing_verifying
I've tried to follow the tutorial before, but it's either my key generation is wrong, I didn't follow the tutorial correctly, or both.

My current code generates an error, I've already debugged it and it generates the error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to implement cryptographic functionality yourself, instead of using a mature library?

Comment: Do you know of any libraries that would be good for what I'm doing?

Comment: Also, because its a good learning experience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For debugging help, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (make sure it's *minimal*), including full error traceback.

Comment: My question wasn't for debugging, I understand the error I'm just trying to figure out how to reprogram it, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Your program isn't runable (apart from the obvious import error, `max_mod` is not defined). So since you don't provide more error information (fuller traceback) it's hard to help.

Comment: No line given which has this error, no debugging details, no full traceback, no runnable code. Voting to close; please try and put yourself in the position of the one reading this question and ask yourself if you yourself would have enough info.

Comment: Note that you are not doing elliptic curves correctly either, but you are getting there. Elliptic curves for cryptography are defined over finite fields, and the arithmetic for finite fields is different. However, it's still relatively easy to do with python.

Comment: I have reedited it, but my main question is how to implement a sign function, the line which had this error was:
p2 = gen_points(r_x/s, public_key).
Apparently, the gen_points function was not returning anything, can anyone explain how to fix that error?